# Long living object in RobotFramework

Tags: python, pytest, robotframework

I'm interested in realization some kind similar behaviour as in pytest fixture with session scope:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init___(self):
       self.actions = []

@fixture(scope='session')
def live_during_session():
    return MyClass()


def test_1(live_during_session):
    live_during_session.actions.append('test_1')

def test_2(live_during_session):
    live_during_session.actions.append('test_2')

print(live_during_session.actions)  # [test_1, test_2]
```

I want to have a long-living instance that would be available for the entire session or suite run.

Is there some solution?

Comment: How do you plan to use this code in Robot Framework, please show an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add *ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'SUITE'* this way only one instatnce of the library will be created for the test suite. Insted of having instance for each test

```
class ExampleLibrary:
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'SUITE'

    def __init__(self):
        self._counter = 0

    def count(self):
        self._counter += 1
        print(self._counter)

    def clear_counter(self):
        self._counter = 0
```

You can read about library scope [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-scope)

Comment: More over `GLOBAL` scope will result in one instance for the whole execution across multiple suites.

Comment: While @BenceKaulics 's comment is true in *most* cases, there is a gotcha, if the library takes in parameters and there are multiple testsuites or resource files, its not quaranteed that only one instance is created..